# HTML5 grid layout

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Since I am beginner and so far I have been only working with Bootstrap, I am used to their conventional layouts with rows and columns, I am wondering how do you make this kind of layout where the left green column, this side bar looks like it is put on top or over the usual container with columns. 
Can anyone please explain how it is done?

[This is the example web page](http://www.fjellrevenshop.no/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the CSS property of `z-index`.

What z-index does is that it can be used how high you want your contents on the page to be. This meaning, if there are two `div`s on top of each other, the div with the higher `z-index` will be displayed on top of the `div` with the lower index.

Please note that `z-index` only works when you `position` your content

[Here](http://www.cgscomputing.com/36558/zindex.html) is a basic example of `z-index` being used with divs.

Hope I helped.

Comment: An example would be great, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Just a sec, It will take some time for me to type one up. But feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Added an example. Have a look at the page code if you are having trouble understanding. :)

Comment: this has actually non to do with html5 ^^

Comment: It actually does, as he is using HTML code to make the actual webpage.

Comment: z-index works in IE 4 and html5 wasn't even in mind when IE 4 came out so, sorry, its not :) btw. you may should add the info that z-index only works on positioned elements